# Returning to the previous Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I only have one activity which is the `MainActivity`. All other parts are in the form of fragments.

[image: Sidebar]
[image: Announcement List]
[image: Announcement Detail]
So if we go to Announcements,
 basically, what'll happen is

```
MainActivity -> AnnouncementsFragment-> AnnouncementDetailFragment
```

What I wanted to happen is when the user presses the back key twice, he returns to the previous Fragment instead of closing it.

```
MainActivity <- AnnouncementsFragment <- AnnouncementDetailFragment
```

As per research, I found this code which unfortunately don't work with my instance. I am using, by the way, a Navigation Sidebar.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

**Layout/content_main**

Basically, what I did in the `content_main.xml` is just containers for replaceable data.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.techdepot_ph.maco.iannounce.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/sti_overlay_bg"
        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/root_layout">

    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Initiating the Fragment**

What I did on initiating the fragment is when a user clicks an item in the Navigation Bar

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_message) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Create Announcement");

        fragment = new CreateMessageFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.root_layout, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_announcements) {

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Announcements");

        fragment = new AnnouncementsFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.root_layout, fragment);
        ft.commit();

    } 

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you commit your new fragment, add your previous fragment to backstack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       // Add this transaction to the back stack
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

Read more here.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#addToBackStack(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

when loading your fragment add them to backstack

```
fragment = new CreateMessageFragment();
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.root_layout, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack(null)
    ft.commit();
```

and in your activity back press

```
 private Boolean exit = false;
  @Override
     public void onBackPressed() {
if (exit) {

      if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0 ){
       getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
          }
 else
          super.onbackpress();       
              } 

       else {

                  exit = true;
                  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          exit = false;
                      }
                  }, 3 * 1000);
              }
```